# Category on NSObject to get instance of AppDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need access to my core data managed object context often, and instead of getting an instance of the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` and storing it in a variable every time in every class, I was wondering if it would be ok to do this:

```
@interface NSObject(DelegateExtension)
- (AppDelegate*)appDelegate;
@end

@implementation 
NSObject(DelegateExtension)
- (AppDelegate*)appDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
@end
```

so then I can just do `self.appDelegate` anywhere in my code.

Is anything wrong with doing this that might night be obvious? Is it bad programming practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Categories on NSObject -- keeping it safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693646/categories-on-nsobject-keeping-it-safe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a global variable to point to the app delegate.

In MyAppDelegate.h:

```
extern MyAppDelegate* AppDelegate;
```

In MyAppDelegate.m:

```
MyAppDelegate* AppDelegate = nil;

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        AppDelegate = self;
        …
    }
}
```

Now anyone who imports "MyAppDelegate.h" can use the `AppDelegate` variable to access your app delegate.

Comment: Oh nice..what effect would adding `static` to the declaration have?

Comment: `static` limits the visibility to the file in which the declaration is made -- it would be contrary to your needs.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_appDelegate", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o`

Comment: I set appDelegate = self in applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: Do you have `AppDelegate* appDelegate = nil;` in your AppDelegate.m file?

Comment: Weird, I overrided the init method of AppDelegate and put a NSLog statement in there, and it showed up twice. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Set a breakpoint.  If it's really being called twice the stack trace will tell you why.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the debugger, but I hit the "step over" button several times, and it repeated the execution of init in the AppDelegate class..

Comment: I commented out **everything** in my AppDelegate.m, so nothing occurs in the entire execution of the app except the init method, and it **still** gets called twice..

Comment: Turns out I had an AppDelegate object in one of my XIBs

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you could add a preprocessor macro (or a static C function) to your `Prefix.pch` file:

```
#define AppDelegateInstance() (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

This will make your app delegate accessible from anywhere in your code, and there is no chance of conflicting with any existing methods named `appDelegate`.

Comment: To use, you would just type `AppDelegateInstance()` anywhere you want to access the app delegate instance. The preprocessor will substitute it with `(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` before compiling.

Comment: But could you still access properties with a macro, I wonder?

Comment: Yes. If your app delegate has a property named `foo`, you should still be able to access it using `[AppDelegateInstance() foo]`, which will expand to `[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] foo]`.

Comment: Excellent, +1.  I would have gone with a constants header file, but the prefix seems more appropriate and efficient.

Comment: @CameronSpickert : this method works fine.. Consider if we have to change value for the appdelegate property foo, how to do that..?

Comment: @ManojEllappan `[AppDelegate() setFoo:@"newFoo"];`

Answer (score 2):

`NSObject` doesn't have any meaningful connection to `UIApplication` or its delegate. From a design standpoint, I think doing this would be a hack in the bad sense. There are three other solutions that I can come up with off the top of my head that I think would be millions of times better:

1. Function, whose declaration is in a header which is imported by your prefix header.
2. Category on `UIApplication`, which is actually a class that has something to do with the action you're trying to take.
3. Global pointer, like `NSApp` on OS X*, that's set up as the first thing in your program to point to the `UIApplication` instance.
4. (Four solutions!) Global pointer to the app delegate.

See [On lazy instantiation and convenience methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497966/on-lazy-instantiation-and-convenience-methods/8498400#8498400) for info on implementing 3 or 4.

---

*Really don't understand why they didn't do this on iOS.

Comment: @mohabitar: I've added a link to an answer of mine that I think will give you the idea. Let me know if you need more info and I'll expand. Interesting question, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's safe, so long as you *know* that apple doesn't or won't have a method named appDelegate in the near future.  Subclassing is the preferred method, especially because NSObject is a root class. But, that would require class posing, something deprecated completely in OSX 10.5+ and never even a viable option on iOS devices.